# My application is throwing Gunicorn error:gunicorn.errors. HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

Gettining this gunicorn error. How to solve it??

```
"/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Docker command:

```
FROM python:3.7
#work with directory
WORKDIR /app
#copy all the files in the base file in the app
COPY . /app/
#Download and install a dependency
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
#list down all the contents in the current in current directory in a long format for debugging and inspection purpose
RUN ls -la ./
#only listen to port no 80
EXPOSE 80
#Tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-b", ":80", "main:app", "--preload", "--timeout", "300"]
```

Comment: There's probably more detail in e.g. logs – there's a reason why a worker would fail to boot.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' 
I'm using a docker file to create the command..here it is
EXPOSE 80
#Tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-b", ":80", "main:app", "--preload", "--timeout", "300"]

Comment: Well, there you have it – no module named `main`. Show the entire dockerfile in your question.

Comment: updated with docker command